# neo4j - delete node after deleting relationship if relationships = 0

Tags: c#, neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j, neo4jclient

Let us take this example: I have a data set with murderers that killed each other. We have `murderer-killed->murderer`.

```
 neo4jClient.Cypher
.Match("(murderer1:MurdererNode)-[k:KILLED]->(murderer2:MurdererNode)
.Where((MurdererNode murderer1) => murderer1.Name == "someName")
.AndWhere((MurdererNode murderer2) => murderer2.Name == "someName2")
.Delete("k")
```

Now, in my application, I am passing some parameters and deleting the 'killed' relationship between two nodes. It may happen that either node will have no incoming 'killed' or outgoing 'killed' relationships right AFTER performing the deletion. In this case only, i.e. when both incoming and outgoing equal 0, I want to delete the node from my database.

After deleting a relationship, I want to perform "IF node.out_relationship.count = 0 and node.in_relationship.count = 0, then DELETE node" for both nodes having participated in the relationship. In other words I want to perform some post-relationship-deletion work on my nodes.

I was thinking to enhance my query as follows:

```
 neo4jClient.Cypher
.Match("(murderer1:MurdererNode)-[k:KILLED]->(murderer2:MurdererNode)
.Where((MurdererNode murderer1) => murderer1.Name == "someName")
.AndWhere((MurdererNode murderer2) => murderer2.Name == "someName2")
.Delete("k")
.With("murderer1,murderer2")
.Match("(murderer1)-[:KILLED]-()")
.Where("count(murderer1)=0")
.Delete(murderer1)
.Match("(murderer2)-[:KILLED]-()")
.Where("count(murderer2)=0")
.Delete(murderer2)
```

(Obviously I could break up the queries into other sessions, but I think that keeping everything in one session, reusing the node, would be more efficient.)

Anyway I'm not sure how much sense this change makes, it looks ugly, and it feels like I'm bending over backwards.

How can I continue? I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your logic for both murderer1 and murderer2 is identical, if you create a 2-element list for both murderers and then UNWIND them to a single variable you can apply that logic to both of them at once.

The Cypher for this would be:

```
MATCH (murderer1:MurdererNode)-[k:KILLED]->(murderer2:MurdererNode)
WHERE murderer1.Name = "someName"
 AND murderer2.Name = "someName2"
DELETE k
WITH [murderer1, murderer2] as murderers
UNWIND murderers as murderer // now each on its own row under "murderer"
WITH murderer
WHERE size((murderer)-[:KILLED]-()) = 0
DETACH DELETE murderer // will delete any additional relationships
```

You could also use a FOREACH (over the filtered collection of the 2 murderers where the :KILLED degree is 0) and do the DETACH DELETE there instead of using UNWIND.

I am not entirely sure how that would be expressed with neo4jclient, but that should be a blueprint that you can use to work on that.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly for my purposes! Could you elaborate on why you changed my DELETE to a DETACH DELETE?

Comment: Sure, when you just use DELETE, that will only succeed if there are no relationships on that node. From the query, we're sure there are no :KILLED relationships on that node, but we have no idea if there are any other relationships connected. By using DETACH DELETE we avoid any error and just delete all relationships first from the node and then the node itself.